# error no available encoding when using su with and without hyphen in linux

Tags: linux, bash, suse

Please whoever can help me to resolve this problem,

- with su without hyphen: (su)

*chage -l EmergencyUser*

**conversion from `ISO-8859-1' to`UTF-8' not available.**

Minimum:    0

Maximum:    99999

Warning:    7

Inactive:   -1

Last Change:        Never

Password Expires:   Never

Password Inactive:  Never

Account Expires:    Never

- su with hyphen (su -): no the bold line as above

*chage -l EmergencyUser*

Minimum:    0

Maximum:    99999

Warning:    7

Inactive:   -1

Last Change:        Never

Password Expires:   Never

Password Inactive:  Never

Account Expires:    Never

**Why appear the bold line like that. and how to fix it withoutusing "su -"**

Answer (score 0):

The environment is not the same. Run `env` after executing `su` (with and without the hyphen) to see the difference.

Here is an extract of the man page for su (see the section about the hyphen option):

> **su - run a command with substitute user and group ID**
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   su [options] [-] [user [argument...]]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> su allows to run commands with a substitute user and group ID.
>
> When called without arguments, su defaults to running an
>   interactive    shell as root.
>
> For backward compatibility, su defaults to not change the current
>   directory and to only set the environment variables HOME and SHELL
>   (plus USER and LOGNAME if the target user is not root).  It is
>   recommended to always use the --login option (instead of its shortcut 
>   -) to avoid side effects caused by mixing environments.
>
> OPTIONS
>
> **-, -l, --login** *Start the shell as a login shell with an
>   environment similar to a real login:*
>
> ```
>  o      clears all the environment variables except TERM
>  o      initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL,
>                     USER, LOGNAME, and PATH
>  o      changes to the target user's home directory
>
>  o      sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make
>                     the shell a login shel
> ```

Comment: Hi sir, but you can show me what is problem in the sentence "conversion from ISO-8859-1' toUTF-8' not available.". I dont think this problem related to environment variables which you address. Thanks a lot

Comment: I suspect an encoding incompatibility between your terminal and shell/env variables.  Can you copy/past here the output of `env` after executing su (in both cases: with and without the hyphen)?

Comment: I got it. the problem in LANG variable, sir. Thanks so much